# How to determine last element in a row with Isotope

Tags: jquery-isotope

I'd like to be able to put a special class on the last element of a row in an isotope-sorted layout. I need some special styles to get applied to it. I was using nth-element but this doesn't work after sorting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed this by doing math, searching elements which's left border left less than "element width" space in the container.